# Symbolize Rubberband Tracker as it tracks

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, symbology

I am trying to symbolize a rubberband tracker as it is drawing.  The default symbol is a simple black line.  When setting the symbol of the line in the ScreenDisplay method and and calling DrawPolyline, the symbol I have set does appear but this is after the draw has completed.

I would like to have the symbol I set be shown once a single point has been created (while its tracking the next point), not just when the construction of the line has completed.

This functionality seems to be possible as I can easily do it in ArcMap - I can select any symbol and then create a new line feature and it displays the selected symbol while I draw it.

Edit: I noticed that it doesn't refresh as cleanly as the built in ArcMap tools do either.  Strange, could there be some side effect happening?  I've added two clips of what I experience and what I would like to have happen and exactly how I would like the line to look.

Result from this code:

[image: Default Rubberband]

What I would like:

[image: Arrow Symbol Rubberband]

Relevant Code:

```
IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (int)esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);

// Custom symbol I create gets cast as ISymbol...
ISymbol symbol = (ISymbol)cartographicLineSymbol;

IRubberBand2 rubberBand = new RubberLineClass();
ICurve2 rubberLine = (ICurve2)rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, symbol);

screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
screenDisplay.DrawPolyline(rubberLine);
screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
```

Comment: Did you try setting `ISymbol.ROP2  = esriRasterOpCode.esriROPNotXOrPen` ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13926/dragging-feature-in-arcobjects-and-arcgis-engine-axmapcontrol/13933#13933

Comment: I just tried this and it did not change the outcome.  I've added some animations of what I experience and what I would like to see.  While creating the animations I noticed that the rubberband from my custom tool does not refresh as quickly as the built in ArcMap tools do.